# How can I allow individual developers to have their own space to create git repositories?

Tags: ubuntu, git, version-control

I have a server that is essentially a gitosis setup.  I have a git user that has access to all the shared repositories.  What I would like to do is have each developer be able to have their own "area" on this server to create their own repositories.  I'd like these areas to be able to be viewable via gitweb.  How can this be done that would require the least maintenance in terms of adding users and repositories?

One obvious solution would be to just allow each developer to create repositories on the git login and have branches named something like `<devname>-<reponame>`.  But I could see this getting unmanageable as the number of developers grows.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of the specifics of git web (I am just getting into git, I like it!) but the following should work in general case either way

1. Create a gituser group.  Add the main user for git to this group (what ever user is running git hub etc)
2. Have each developer be given a username to the system, and belong to the gituser group
3. In each new users home directory create a folder that is read/write/execute by all in the gituser group
4. Add that folder to git hubs list of folders to look at for repositories to process (I assume that if it is like hosting webpages this should be pretty straightforward but I lack knowledge)

Now, if you put all but #1 in a script, you should be able to run one command with a username and password as arguments that will make all your magic happen.

Comment: 1, 2, and 3 are straightforward, but 4's kind of what I'm asking about.  I haven't got a clue how to do #4.